# Need help understanding a proof about $N_{2}$ latin squares.

Tags: latin-square

I understand what the author is doing in Theorem 1.3.1 [intercalate proof](http://books.google.com/books?id=j5xwpnK4x18C&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=intersection+of+two+subsquares&source=bl&ots=uhpIs3NbRD&sig=Dk3roDX4-HMv5pu6IoA19qtfMWs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ML9XVL67J4GqNtOLgoAP&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=intersection%20of%20two%20subsquares&f=false),  however I don't see how this proof relies on the fact that $n$ needs to be odd.  It seems to me the same logic holds for any $n$ (though, I do know there are latin square defined by $L_{i,j} = i + j\mod{n}$ with intercalates when $n$ is even).  Hope this is clear, thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to me that they desire to partition the $n$ rows into $2$ (approximately) equal-size sets.  However, you can't do that when $n$ is odd; instead, you can divide $n-1$ rows into two equal sized sets.  But I may be way off...

Answer (score 2):

Their proof is terribly written, here is a better version which shows why $n$ needs to be odd.

With $L$ as they defined it, an intercalate would consist of $i\neq \ell$ and $j\neq k$ so that $L_{i,j}=L_{\ell,k}$ and $L_{i,k}=L_{\ell,j}$, so that
$$
i+j=\ell +k
$$
$$
i+k=\ell+j
$$
Subtracting these, we get
$$
j-k=k-j=-(j-k)
$$
So, $j-k$ solves the equation $x=-x$. This equation has only one solution when $n$ is odd, namely, $x=0$ (can you see why? check it for $n=3$, $n=5$ if not). This is a contradiction, since $j-k=0$ contradicts $j\neq k$.

The reason this proof doesn't work when $n$ is even is because $x=-x$ has **two** solutions in that case. For example, , both $0=-0$ and $2=-2$ (mod $4$).